# error updating into form textbox from web element

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have an excel userform that I need to update with data from a website. 
Gett the data from the site is done and verified! But when I try to update the data to an excel form it remains blank!

```
forms!UserForm1!envelope = HTMLdoc.all.no_projet.Value
forms!UserForm1!envelope.Refresh
MsgBox HTMLdoc.all.no_projet.Value' this shows the good data and is valid
MsgBox forms!UserForm1!envelope  ' this shows as empty
```

I`ve also tried to add a refresh to the onchange event of the form textbox to no avail.

```
Private Sub envelope_Change()
Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

Have been away too long.

thanks

Pete

Comment: The above code looks correct. If you can add more detail to your question, it would help debug further

Comment: `forms!UserForm1!` looks like `Access` Form syntax. I verified by trying in Excel and it errored out on me. Where are you calling the data from? Or what if you try `UserForm1.Envelope = ...`

Comment: hey Scott , your suggestion worked, lopped off the Form. just put UserFRorm1.envelope.

Comment: Just one mopre question which is how do I mark the question as answered! Searched through 10 pages in the Meta and  several other help pages, but still don't see where. Seems to me there was a green tag but don't see it!